# Session in Laravel 4.2 doesn't works

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4, hosting

I have a problem with session in laravel , I use cookies driver

In localhost works fine , but in shared hosting (Hostgator) dosen't work

Same code.

This is the code in Route.php

```
Route::get('/SetSession',function(){
    Session::put('Domain','http://example.com');
    return Session::get('Domain');
});
Route::get('/GetSession',function(){
    return Session::get('Domain');
});
```

I don't know what is the problem , in shared host empty value , but in localhost works fine.

Comment: Please check phpinfo..

Comment: I am assuming that your session driver should be - file, please check it out in session.php file under config directory. If yes, then I would suggest to check the correct file permission over "storage" directory inside app..

Comment: Can you please put session.php in your question?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/XPeC3zb6f898tcsxUthSGg

Comment: Is "se" folder having right permission?

Comment: @kamal yes , it has 777 permission

Comment: Can you remove - http://taq1.almubarmg.com/ for time being from domain and check?

Comment: @Kamal still doesn't works. It is strange problem , it works fine in my localhost , do you think the problem from hostgator ?

Comment: Perhaps, yes I think so... cause I have the same scenario and I have transferred everything from my local to server and it seems working fine..

Comment: thanks @Kamal , two days to solve this problem , and 3 days waiting response from hostgator support. thank you

Comment: OMG!! This is crazy..

Answer (score 0):

Yes , I found a problem , I have a space before php tag in Route.php

Like this :

```
   <?php 


?>
```